# Is this WSDL valid?

Tags: java, linux, web-services, wsdl, wsdl2java

In running a `WSDL2Java` [sample](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43598502/262852) I wanted to inspect the generated `WSDL` because I was having problems with the [client code Netbeans generated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43571916/262852) from a web service.  Is [this](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL) `WSDL` valid or invalid?  If invalid, why is it "advertised", in the `URL`, as well as in the `XML`, as `WSDL`?

Running the `WSDL2Java` [validator from the CLI](https://askubuntu.com/a/908608/45156) shows it as invalid:

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ jars/apache-cxf-3.1.11/bin/wsdlvalidator https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL
WSIBP Validator found <{https://www.w3schools.com/xml/}TempConvertHttpPost> is NOT a SOAP binding
WSDLValidator Error : 
line 127 column 66 of https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'part' must appear on element 'mime:content'.

line 136 column 66 of https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL: cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'part' must appear on element 'mime:content'.

thufir@doge:~$
```

However, that's, literally, the first time I've used the `WSDL2Java` API at all.  Perhaps there's an [online](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105515/24327) validator which runs as a web service?

While I wasn't able to save the report, it *seems* to be valid, after downloading the page and then uploading it:

https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/service/service/893784871?version=1

Comment: WSDL is ok, checked as ClientService in .Net, but service is [down](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit);

Answer (score 1):

The aforementioned WSDL contains three different bindings: soap 1.1, soap 1.2 and http, meaning there are three different ways/protocols to call a temperaturte converter webservice as you can see here: 
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit

But WSDL tooling and interoperability works best if you stick to just soap 1.1 binding. For learning purposes find a WSDL with just soap 1.1 binding.